# Function giving me error; thinks input is nonetype

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code to determine the greatest prime palindrome less than 1000, and am getting an error message I don't really understand how to fix: the error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sebpole/Documents/EvalPrimePallindrome.py", line 43, in     <module>
    if GPF(c) == c:
  File "/Users/sebpole/Documents/EvalPrimePallindrome.py", line 37, in GPF
    la = fac(int(la))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Which I believe means at some point in my program an integer is being turned into not-an-integer and then plugged into a function that needs an integer? Not really sure where that's happening though...Here's the code:

```
#Find the largest prime palindrome less than 1000
primePalis = []
def isolate(x, y):
    x = str(x)
    r = x[len(x)-y]
    return int(r)

def palcheck(x):
    i=1
    while i < len(str(x)):
        if isolate(x, i) != isolate(x, len(str(x))-i+1):
            return 0
        i = i+1
    return 1

def fac(x):
    a = 2
    while a <= x:
        if  a**2 > x:
            return 0
            break
        elif x%a == 0:
        return x/a
        break
    if a!=2:
        a = a+2
    elif a == 2:
        a = a+1

def GPF(x):
    la = fac(x)
    lb = la
    if la == 0:
        return x
    while la != 0:
        lb = la
        la = fac(la)
    return lb

c = 1
while c <= 1000:
    if palcheck(c) == 1:
        if GPF(c) == c:
            primePalis.append(c)
    c = c+1

print(max(primePalis))
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Side note: Is there an easier way to get the website to recognize my code as code that's not manually hitting the space bar four times before every line of my code?

Comment: For your side question: You can press `Ctrl+K` to indent all selected text as code. You can also press a button above the editing area. Or just indent the code in your editor if for some reason you can't do those, copy, outdent back.

Comment: Also, an aside of mine: when posting a nontrivial code sample, you should add comments indicating where the line numbers in your traceback point, since Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter doesn't render line numbers. (The right ones could be lost if the code is excerpted or omits boilerplate.)

Comment: Before anything, fix indentation on line 23,  `return x/a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `fac()` doesn't doesn't explicitly return anything if control reaches the end, so it returns `None`.

A simple fix is to add `return a` at the end:

```
def fac(x):
    a = 2
    #...
    if a!=2:
        a = a+2
    elif a == 2:
        a = a+1
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

The `la = fac(int(la))` error line doesn't really seem to be preset in the code you posted, but the problem probably is that `fac(1)` doesn't return anything, which means its return value is `None`.